# jQuery Validate conditional error messages for same field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I would want to different error messages for a single field  based on conditions like below.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    //...


    ..//

    $("#aID").validate({
            rules: {
                reason: "required",
                aic: "required"
                aAmt:{
                    required: function (element) {          
                    var err;
                    var new_balance = Math.round(100*beg_balance)/100 - Math.abs(Math.round(100*adjustAmount)/100);
            if ((parseInt(aAmount) >= parseInt(a_limit_amount))) {
                err = "123";                        
                return true;
            }
            else if (new_balance)
            {

                err = "321";
                return true;
            }
            return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            },
            messages: {
                reason:"Please select a reason code.",
                aic: "Please select a credit AIC.",
                pwdOverride: err
            },

    });
```

There is an option like below

```
messages: {
  RoutingNumber: {
    required:"Message1",
    digits: "Message2",
    rangelength: "Message 3"
  }
}
```

But mine doesn't have any built it validation methods from this plugin. 
Any help on how to achieve it?

What I mean for built in validation is if you see my else loop for `aAmt` : `rules`, it doesn't fit in jQuery Validate's built in validation such as:  [List of built in validation methods](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/#link-list-of-built-in-validation-methods)

Comment: *"But mine doesnt have any built it validation from jquery"* ~ What does "mine" refer to?  If you don't install the jQuery Validate plugin, then you cannot use the code above.

Comment: @sparky I have updated the validation that I would want to perform.

Comment: What does *"mine doesnt have any built it validation from jquery"* mean??  Do you have the [jQuery Validate plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org) installed?

Comment: Once again, we cannot see the ***rendered HTML markup*** of your form so we cannot formulate the exact solution... just a general concept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have some serious syntax issues here as indicated in my comments below.

```
$("#aID").validate({
    rules: {
        reason: "required",
        aic: "required" // <- MISSING a comma here
        aAmt: {
            required: function(element) {
                var err;
                var new_balance = Math.round(100 * beg_balance) / 100 - Math.abs(Math.round(100 * adjustAmount) / 100);
                if ((parseInt(aAmount) >= parseInt(a_limit_amount))) {
                    err = "123";
                    return true;
                } else if (new_balance) {
                    err = "321";
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
                }  // <- REMOVE extra brace
            }
        }
    },
    messages: {
        reason: "Please select a reason code.",
        aic: "Please select a credit AIC.",
        pwdOverride: err   // <- no such field defined in 'rules'
    }
});
```

1. You are missing a comma right after the `aic` rule.
2. You have an extra brace within your conditional function.
3. Within `messages` you are referring to a field named `pwdOverride`, but there is no such field defined within `rules`.  How can you define a validation error message on a field that has no validation rules?
4. Your conditional function for custom messages should be contained within the `messages` object, not the `rules` object.  `rules` is for defining the rules and `messages` is for defining the messages.

**Updated**:

```
$("#aID").validate({
    rules: {
        reason: "required",
        aic: "required",
        aAmt: "required"
    },
    messages: {
        reason: "Please select a reason code.",
        aic: "Please select a credit AIC.",
        aAmt: {
            required: function(element) {
                var err = "this field is required"; // default message
                var new_balance = Math.round(100 * beg_balance) / 100 - Math.abs(Math.round(100 * adjustAmount) / 100);
                if ((parseInt(aAmount) >= parseInt(a_limit_amount))) {
                    err = "123";
                } else if (new_balance) {
                    err = "321";
                }
                return err;  // <- display the custom message
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Since **you have not shown us the HTML markup of your form**, I can only provide a generic proof-of-concept example:  [jsfiddle.net/3of700am/](http://jsfiddle.net/3of700am/)

**NOTES**:

- Pay attention to you JavaScript console because it will tell you about many of these syntax errors.
- Properly format and intent your code so it's easier to read and troubleshoot.  Once formatted, extra/missing brackets/braces are easy to find.

Comment: Thanks so much. Used the code in the messages section and it helped. I have another field for password which is not a required field but other than that applies same condition as above? It works for the condition however even though i return false in the final else block action is not getting called.(case when no error message is returned) Page Uses the same form submit. Updated my code for pwd.

Comment: @JNPW, please do not replace the entire content of your original question after it's been answered.  It disconnects the existing answers and does not help any future readers.  If you have a new question, please post a new question.  Thanks.